# How to prove that a function induces a smooth structure (on $\mathbb{R}$)?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm somewhat new to Differential Geometry, although I can work with submanifolds on $\mathbb{R}^n$. But the general notion of a smooth structure is still confusing. I've already found some questions and answers on my perticular Problem, but none of the answers were quite satisfactory for me. I think I got the point, however I'm not quite sure if I inderstood correctly. The Problem is as follows:

The map $f(x) = x^3$ as a chart, induces a smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$. This is diffeomorphic to the standard smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$, however it is not the same.

I have the following Problems (and maybe already solutions if I understood correctly):

1. Why does $f$ even define a smooth structure?
2. Why are the smooth structures diffeomorphic, although they are different structures?
3. A more general approach on 1, namely: Does every smooth, bijective function $\mathbb{R}$ to itself define a smooth structure?

For Problem 1:
The only problem is with coordinate changes on open neighborhoods of $0$. wlog we can reduce to an open interval $(a,b)$ containing $0$. Then the coordinate changes are $ f \circ f^{-1} = id$, which is a smooth map. Therefore the coordinate changes are smooth Diffeos and $f$ induces a smooth structure.

For Problem 2:
The same Problem as in 1. arises, namely open Intervals containing $0$. But in this case, the chart $f$ and the standard chart $id$ are not compatible, since $id \circ f^{-1} = x^{1/3}$, which is not a smooth function. Therefore the smooth structures are different.
To show that they are diffeomorphic, we want a diffeomorphism $F : (\mathbb{R}, id) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, f)$. I heard that one should take $F(x) := f^{-1}(x) = x^{1/3}$. This map is bijective and smooth as a map between manifolds, since the composition $f \circ F \circ id^{-1} = id$, where the last $id$ is smooth as a map $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in the usual sense.

For Problem 3: I reckon yes (as long as $g^{-1}$ is continuous). So my attempt:
Lets say we have a smooth, bijective function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then on any open interval, the coordinate changes are $g \circ g^{-1} = id$, which is a smooth function. Therefore $g$ defines a smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$.
But if $g^{-1}$ happens to not be smooth (in the usual sense), then $g$ induces another smooth structure than $id$ (as in 2). Still, taking the isomorphism to be $g^{-1}$, we get that the smooth structures are diffeomorphic.

I guess this works, but I'm not sure. Also, just taking the diffeomorphism in 2. and 3. to be $f^{-1}$ seems kind of "sketchy". It looks like this "trick" works also for $\mathbb{R}^n$, which cannot be true (especially for $n = 4$ as far as I know). Why does it work in this case, and what am I missing?

Comment: What can state the definition of smooth structure?

Comment: Your solutions to 1 and 2 look correct to me.